# Minimal Silverlight example

Tags: c#, silverlight, boo

What is the really minimal example of Silverlight application?

For example, I made the following example with IronPython:

```
from System.Windows import Application
from System.Windows.Controls import Canvas, TextBlock

canvas = Canvas()
textblock = TextBlock()
textblock.FontSize = 24
textblock.Text = 'Hello!'
canvas.Children.Add(textblock)

Application.Current.RootVisual = canvas
```

Then I used **chiron** and it created a .xap file. No (explicit) XAML, no nothing. Is it possible to do the same in, say, C#? One source file which I could compile from command line? If so, what would the source code be?

My motivation is to try and create silverlight app with unconventional languages, right now I am stuck at Boo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MimimalSilverlightApp
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            this.Startup += this.Application_Startup;
        }

        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            var canvas = new Canvas();

            var textblock = new TextBlock();
            textblock.FontSize = 24;
            textblock.Text = "Hello!";
            canvas.Children.Add(textblock);

            this.RootVisual = canvas;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found an F# example [here](http://jyliao.blogspot.com/2008/11/f-and-silverlight-20.html).

Made a Boo example based on it. The source code:

```
namespace Hello
import System
import System.Windows
import System.Windows.Controls

class MyPage(UserControl):
    def constructor():
        canvas = Canvas()
        textblock = TextBlock()
        textblock.FontSize = 24
        textblock.Text = "Hello!"
        canvas.Children.Add(textblock)

        self.Content = canvas

class MyApp(Application):

    def constructor():      
        Startup += onStartup


    def onStartup(sender, e):

        self.RootVisual = MyPage()
```

Built with:

```
booc -nostdlib -target:library -lib:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v2.0\Reference Assemblies","C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v2.0\Libraries\Client" -r:System.Windows.dll -r:System.Windows.Controls.dll Hello.boo
```

The AppManifest.xaml:

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment" 
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
            EntryPointAssembly="Hello" 
            EntryPointType="Hello.MyApp" RuntimeVersion="2.0.31005.0">
  <Deployment.Parts>
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Hello" Source="Hello.dll" />
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="Boo.Lang" Source="Boo.Lang.dll" />
  </Deployment.Parts>
</Deployment>
```

Then made an ordinary .zip file containing AppManifest.xaml, Hello.dll and Boo.Lang.dll (one of Boo libraries from it's directory) and renamed it into hello.xap.

An html to look at it:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<object id="SilverlightPlugin" data="data:application/x-silverlight,"
 type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="450" height="540">
  <param name="source" value="hello.xap"/>

  <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=124807" style="text-decoration: none;">
    <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181"
     alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style: none"/>
  </a>
</object>

</body>
</html>
```

The resulting hello.xap is 43 KB, which is much better than 1.5 MB that I got with IronPython and DLR.